# i have erro Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, laravel-echo

in my app.js in laravel blog

```
import './bootstrap';
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
});
```

i give me in browser
app.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at app.js:6:1

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: not it dosn't answer

Comment: Are you using mix?

Comment: i am using vite

Comment: `require` is a CommonJS-specific way to load external JS. This doesn’t exist in browsers by default, and on Node.js, this will not work in module code. Since you’re using `import`, you’re using ECMAScript modules; CommonJS should not be used in this case.